# Different results on LeetCode by Submit Solution and Run Code

Tags: java, c++

I am working on the LeetCode question [Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/description/). But I got two different results between Run Code and Submit Solution. My c++ code is

```
class Solution {
public:
    int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
        int* a = new int[257];
        int ans = 0;
        int n = s.size();
        for (int j = 0, i = 0; j < n; j++) {
            i = i > a[s[j]] ? i : a[s[j]];
            ans = ans > j - i +1 ? ans : j - i + 1;
            a[s[j]] = j + 1;
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

And two outputs are
[image]
I don't know what's wrong with my code. Besides, my c++ code is written by learning his website java answer

```
public class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        int n = s.length(), ans = 0;
        int[] index = new int[128]; // current index of character
        // try to extend the range [i, j]
        for (int j = 0, i = 0; j < n; j++) {
            i = Math.max(index[s.charAt(j)], i);
            ans = Math.max(ans, j - i + 1);
            index[s.charAt(j)] = j + 1;
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike Java, C++ does not zero heap memory for you.

Comment: `return ans + 1;` See if you can trick it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0, i = 0; j < n; j++) {
        i = i > a[s[j]] ? i : a[s[j]];
```

Since `a` is uninitialized, `a[s[j]]` is undefined behavior. You want

```
for (int i=0;i<257;i++)
    a[i]=0;
```

or better a `vector`

```
vector<int> a(257,0);
```

Comment: It is not undefined behaviour, it just contains whatever was there earlier.

Comment: @Bernard Reading uninitialised memory is very much undefined behaviour.

Comment: @It'scominghome After `int* a = new int[257];`, `a[0] .... a[256]` are valid accessible memory, but they may contain any value that an `int` can hold.  Accessing `a[s[j]]` is safe, and will simply be an indeterminate integer value (which might help with optimizations of some algorithms).

Comment: @Bernard Undefined Behavior is not just about safe access.

Comment: @GauravSehgal In my previous comment, I intended "safe" to mean "well-defined behaviour" (the opposite of undefined behaviour).  But seems like I can't edit my comment now because the edit time is up.

Comment: @Bernard There's a quote from the ISO C++14 standard which declares `i = i > a[s[j]] ? i : a[s[j]];` ub at the top of this wiki page, [EXP53-CPP. Do not read uninitialized memory](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/EXP53-CPP.+Do+not+read+uninitialized+memory).

Comment: @It'scominghome Thanks!  I stand corrected.  It is really UB to use indeterminate values.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Java, C++ does not zero heap memory for you.

```
int* a = new int[257];
```

What is the data inside your array `a`?

In Java, `a[0], a[1], ... a[256]` are all equal to zero.  But in C++, `a[0], a[1], ... a[256]` contains random garbage from whatever data was previously at that memory address.

You have to zero the memory first:

```
std::fill_n(a, 257, 0);
```

Or, if you prefer `memset`:

```
std::memset(a, 0, sizeof(int) * 257);
```

---

EDIT: As pointed out by @It'scominghome, value-initialization (C++11) is also possible:

```
int* a = new int[257](); // will zero the array
```

Comment: There's also `int* a = new int[257]();`